# Third Party Tools for Disabling and Enabling Storage device in ubuntu \ LINUX

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, linux-device-driver, redhat

Please help me if any one knows for disabling and enabling USB storage in ubuntu or Linux in windows many applications are available

OR

Share how to disable and enable USB storage using Active Directory policies in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

To blacklist external USB storage, you can do the following:

```
echo "blacklist usb-storage" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then update the init RAM filesystem:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254113/how-do-i-disable-usb-storage)